# Data analysis of multiple log files

Tags: analysis, logfiles

I would like to analyse (Linux-/Switch-) log files with a graphical front-end under Windows. I did a research on several freeware/trialware sites but I didn't find any that fulfil my needs mostly because they are all server-based and for active monitoring/alerting.

It should support:

- I want to use the software on a set of offline files (on a hard-disk)
- It should support filtering lines by string/regex
- It should allow to combine searches from different log files (e.g. find activities from user XYZ in a login- and access log files within a certain time span)
- It should support different log files (they all have the same basic format like: [date/time]: [category]: Message but this might slightly differ if it comes form different programs)
- I want to easily setup these filters
- Not server-based but a stand-alone tool
- Windows

Comment: You probably won't find desktop software because "nobody needs that". I don't see what's wrong with just using the ELK stack either. It's not like you have to keep it running all the time.

Comment: The thing here is simply performance. We don't have a lot powerful Server-PC's and an admin usually uses a (not very powerful) notebook to analyse stuff. I we had enough budget this wouldn't be a problem. So I am also looking for a simple application solution because I hope it will be easier and cheaper to maintain. But it might well be that no such solution exists - that's why I asked the question, because I really didn't find any. :-(